# How to resample a dataframe removing nan values?

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, nan, resampling

I have a large dataframe like [this](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nelakurthisudheer/dataset-for-predicting-watering-the-plants), not used for time time but for a binary classification task. It contains two important feature columns which have more than 60% NaN values. Instead of removing those columns or shrinking the dataframe are there other ways to resample the data and removing those NaNs or substituting them with synthetic values? I was thinking about the SMOTE package but I know it's used for unbalanced dataframes, not for NaNs. Could I use interpolation through NN or I'll risk to generate misleading data?

Comment: I don't know about skewing the dataset, but you can replace NaN value using [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No clear answer on this: depends a lot on your data. If the two columns are really "important" as you say, how can they be so empty? What leads to considering them important? You can easily fake-fill them with [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) or any aggregating function (avg?), but depends on the domain. You can resort to SMOTE, but be sure to have enough data to generate sensible outputs.